# UICollectionView remove incomplete row

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

Is there a decent way to hide/remove last cells in UICollectionView so it's always a block?

Removing last items in `numberOfItemsInSection:` isn't an option. 
If I remove cells from there, next load more(`insertItemsAtIndexPath`) gives me an error.

Hiding cells and adjusting inset doesn't seem like the best option, is there another?

Answer (score 1):

If your data comes from array just detuct one from the array count

```
NSIntger *newArrayCount = Array.count - 1;
```

I'm not sure if thats what you meant

Comment: Yes it comes. This will not work for me. If I reduce count from 25 to 24, next time "load more" occurs, new cell indexPaths will be 24+. This means that 1 cell(item) will be lost.

Comment: r u getting blank cell at the end of your collection view? didn't get your question right maybe